# nodejs express avoid res.redirect after post

Tags: node.js, express

I wanted to optimize and probably reduce Http delay or page load time/TTFB..

Currently, I have a code working well to POST data to a database.
in the express node routes, I got something like that:

```
router.post('/edit', Auth, function(req, res) {
  if ( db.save() ) {
    res.redirect('/my_success_page'); // so redirect as GET(302 status)
  }
}
router.get('/my_success_page', Auth, function(req, res) {
  res.send(. .. ... ... );
}
```

I think, maybe I'm wrong, but if I were able to avoid this "302 redirection", it will certainly reduce the page loading time.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Am I wrong?
2. How can I prevent this redirection and directly display/send the page from the POST route instead of having this redirect+GET ?
   I guess I can copy-paste all the code from the GET route into the POST route.. or maybe I could factorize that into a dedicated "displayPage()" function. Do you have a better suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: The main reason why  we redirect after post is to prevent user hitting refresh button and sending you the same data again.

Comment: That's a good point .. :-) so I'm already doing the right way, right?

Comment: Well, you do it the common way. And I suppose you should stick with it unless you have an expertise to do it some other way. But in that case you will not ask this question here 

Comment: make sense; thanks a lot